# Creating a back up table trigger in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table A which is constantly updated ( insert statements ) by one application. I want to create another table B which consists only few columns of table A. For this I thought of creating a trigger which triggered after insert on Table A, but I don't know how should I write the insert statement inside the trigger. I am not a database expert, so may be I am missing something simple. Please help.

Here is my trigger code:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "MSG_INSERT_TRIGGER" 

AFTER
insert on "ACTIVEMQ_MSGS"

DECLARE
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
begin
execute immediate 'truncate table MSG_BACKUP';
insert into MSG_BACKUP select * from ACTIVEMQ_MSGS;
COMMIT;
end;
```

Comment: Why `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;`, or have you copied that from some other code without knowing what it does? Are you sure you want to truncate the backup table and reinsert the entire `ACTIVEMQ_MSGS` after every insert? Is your actual requirement to insert a single row (with a subset of columns) into `MSG_BACKUP` after an insert has occurred on `ACTIVEMQ_MSGS`?

Comment: Hi Phil, you have got it correct. I have copied it from here and there. Yes, I want to insert a single row into MSG_BACKUP after an insert has occurred on ACTIVEMQ_MSGS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not seem to be good idea: every time a new record gets inserted into Table A, delete everything from table B and copy all records from table A. This will be a huge performance issue, once there is many records in table A.

Wouldn't it be enough to create a view on the desired columns of table A?

If not, that is, you still want to "log" all inserts into an other table, then here you go. (I suppose you want to copy the following fields: f1, f2, f3)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_AI_ACTIVEMQ_MSGS
AFTER INSERT ON ACTIVEMQ_MSGS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO MSG_BACKUP (f1, f2, f3)
  VALUES (:new.f1, :new.f2, :new.f3);            
END TR_AI_ACTIVEMQ_MSGS;
```

Comment: Thanks bpgergo, This is exactly I was looking for. Can I confirm with you if in this Trigger only the new inserted query into Table ACTIVEMQ_MSGS will be copied into MSG_BACKUP ?

Comment: I got little confuse because of this "FOR EACH ROW".

Answer (score 1):

Inside an Oracle trigger the record values are available in de :new pseudo record. Your insert statement may look like this:

```
insert into B (column1, column2) 
values (:new.tableA_col1,:new.tableA_col2)
```